# Strange behaviour when sorting IP addresses. (sort -nu)

Tags: ip-address, bash-scripting, sorting, text-formatting, concatenation

I just tried to `|sort -nu` (numeric & unique) a list of ~30 or so IP addresses and noticed that in addition to culling duplicate lines, it's treating similar lines (i.e. addresses with the same first two or three octets) as identical; and cutting them out as well.

Whats up with that?

To illustrate; you can simulate this scenario, as follows:

---

**stdin**

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..5};
do
    echo "$ip";
done > ip.log
```

```
for ip in 10.1.1.{1..5};
do
    echo "$ip";
done >> ip.log
```

```
cat 'ip.log'
```

---

**stdout**

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
```

---

**stdin**

```
sort -nu 'ip.log'
```

---

**stdout**

```
10.1.1.1
192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell `sort` to sort on version numbers:

```
$ sort -Vu 'ip.log'
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

Alternatively, tell it to sort numerically on all four fields:

```
$ sort -nu -t. -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4  'ip.log'
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```